# why the scripted field in kibana return error result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

kibana version :4.5.0
elastic version :2.3.1

the scripted field (in kibana):

name :`@timestamp._hourOfDay`

script: `doc["dataChange_LastTime"].getHourOfDay()`

---

the date field (in elastic)

```
 "dataChange_LastTime": {
   "type": "date",
   "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
  }
```

but when i use Discover in kibana the result is error.
why that happed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess your script should look like this, without the *get()* function:

```
 doc['dataChange_LastTime'].date.hourOfDay
```

**OR** with the *get()* function

```
 doc['dataChange_LastTime'].date.hourOfDay.get()
```

**OR** try this as well:

```
 doc['dataChange_LastTime'].date.hourOfDay().get()
```

since the field **dataChange_LastTime** is type of *date*.

Comment: I test all but Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"Variable [doc['dataChange_LastTime'].date.hourOfDay.get()] does not follow an allowed format of either doc['field'] or doc['field'].method()"}],

Comment: How about using this **doc['dataChange_LastTime'].date.hourOfDay().getAsText()**

[Source](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-groovy-scripted-field-for-aggregation-visualize-unsupported-script-value/54126/2), could be helpful!

Comment: Oh wait try this over your existing *script* : 

**doc['dataChange_LastTime'].getHourOfDay()** 

Make sure you have the field within *single quote* `'`!

Comment: only doc['dataChange_LastTime'].getHourOfDay()   can be used . but the result seeing not correct. like the pic i uploaded